# ngnix loads blank pages after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, nginx, wordpress

My server runs three wordpress sites and a ubiquiti [unifi](https://www.ubnt.com/software/) controller and after the upgrade the unifi controller works fine but all of the wordpress sites load a blank page that does not contain and error code.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/CMwpPvKF) is my ngnix.conf

[Here](https://pastebin.com/D4tUmDzN) is a snippet of the logs, whats odd is it only throws an error for 1 of the 3 sites and for that site its not constant. For example if I run

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and refresh my browser it will not throw the error every time. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a silly question, but did you reboot after the update to 16.04?  How long has this been happening that you know of?

This white screen for WordPress sounds like it might be a memory issue.  There are a few reasons why the "white screen of death" might appear. It sounds like you have access to php.ini, is your memory limit set to 64M or 128M?  It's easier to set in WordPress itself, with a line like:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

in wp-config.php.  If you have the RAM to spare, set it up on all three sites to give it a boost.

This could be the reason why there's no error message, only occasionally, and why pages fail to load.

Have there been any nginx module changes, or new ones?

I would reboot, increase the memory available to PHP for running WordPress, restart nginx again and see if it appears to go back to normal.

I've always found small, simple steps like this helps to try and narrow down problems without accidentally introducing new ones.